# Replacing DIV with jQuery without removing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a page which is generated and structured as a tree - nested DIVs, etc.. While the user views the page it is possible that some DIVs are updated on the server side and the changes are pushed to the client as JSON data, from which a DIV can be generated.

My problem is that even though I have the old DIV

```
var oldDiv = $('#foo');
```

and I have a new DIV generated by

```
var newDiv = generateDiv(jsonData);
```

I need to update the old one (both attributes and it's content) without deleting it. I was going to use the jQuery method `.replaceWith()` as such

```
oldDiv.replaceWith(newDiv);
```

but according to the documentation it is implemented as remove&create.

> The .replaceWith() method removes content from the DOM and inserts new content in its place with a single call.

How can I update the old DIV without removing it? Is there some nice way to do this, or do I need to do it attribute by attribute?

Comment: why don't want to replace it with a newer version

Comment: if the end result is the same as what you wish for, why is the implementation detail a concern?

Comment: Could you perhaps replace and then hide the old div?

Comment: `oldDiv.innerHTML = newDiv.innerHTML;` is it?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I can't lose focus on the updated element, because the user is still working with it.

Comment: No, unfortunately it has to be the same element, it just needs to be updated. Both content and attributes. I can do it attr byt attr but I was just wondering if there's some sort of replaceWith() which doesn't remove the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've suggested, you may need to replace the attribute values individually. However, if it reads better, you can actually pass an object to the `attr` method, and it will update the values you supply.

```
oldDiv.attr({
    attr1: newDiv.attr1,
    attr2: newDiv.attr2,
    attr3: newDiv.attr3
});
```

If you wanted to loop through the attributes to build the object, you could do that like this.

```
var newAttributes = {};

$.each(newDiv[0].attributes, function(index, attribute){
   newAttributes[attribute.name] = attribute.value;
});

oldDiv.attr(newAttributes);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It will be definitely better. By the way you know of a way to get all the attributes and then do a for cycle, please?

Comment: Thanks! You allready have a +1 from me. This is what I needed, although it's the "plan B" solution. However if someone doesn't come with a more direct way to do this, I will accept it. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done since a `div` element may contain many elements. Why dont u just append the new contents into it.
You can use jquery's `append()` method.

```
$(oldDiv).append("#new_div_id");
```

It will be appended as a child.

If at all you want to update any `<p>` element, you can use the `html()` function to get the contents of a

tag and then

```
old_para_contents=("p").html();
$("p").html(old_para_contents+"New contents");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this isn't what I need. I can't append to it, I need to update the div.

Comment: Your div must be containing some elements rite? why dont u use the after() method to insert the new datas after the last element inside ur div?

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with one solution so far, but if anyone comes up with a better one, I will gladly assign it as the correct one. I need to make this as clean as possible.

```
var oldDiv = $('#my-old-div');
var newDiv = generateDiv(data);

oldDiv.attr("id", newDiv.attr("id"));
oldDiv.attr("class", newDiv.attr("class"));
//...
oldDiv.html(newDiv.html());
```